# AppBar and ListView.length

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, stream

The `title:` of `AppBar` is Text.
If the Body has `ListView` that was made out of Stream.
How can the Text in the title reflect the `ListView` number of items.

```dart
    build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
      appBar:AppBar(title: generateTitle()) // <-- how to pass the snapshot.requiredData.length into here?
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: theStream();
        builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<AnObject>> snapshot) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.requireData.length,            
            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
              CardFromAnObject(snapshot,snapshot.requireData[index], context),
          )
        }
      )
   )
}
```

Comment: How about you move 'StreamBuilder' to Scaffold's parent?

Comment: @KuKu how does that help with the change of the title with the stream?

Comment: I added an answer what I suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add addPostFrameCallback to count your data items and then use totalItem in Appbar.

```
    build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
      appBar:AppBar(title: generateTitle())
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: theStream();
        builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<AnObject>> snapshot) {

              if (latchRefresher != snapshot.requireData.length){//init the field on declare to latchRefresher =-1
                                      SchedulerBinding.instance
                                          .addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {
                                        totalItem = snapshot.data.length;
                                       latchRefresher = snapshot.requireData.length;//this will cause only on change to request a refresh
                                      }));
              }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.requireData.length,            
            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
              CardFromAnObject(snapshot,snapshot.requireData[index], context),
          );
        }
      ));}
```

Comment: that cause an infinite loop . i added a log on a function returns the StreamBuilder and it kept loggin.

Answer (score 1):

You can take help from `addPostFrameCallback` and update the count. I am using counterStream for this example.

```dart
class _TSCState extends State<TSC> {
  var counterStream =
      Stream<int>.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (x) => x).take(15);

  int? itemsCount;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: itemsCount != null
              ? Text("total $itemsCount")
              : Text("loading") // null // or use others expression
          ),
      body: StreamBuilder<int>(
        stream: counterStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
              setState(() {
                itemsCount = snapshot.data!;
              });
            });
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text("Item $index"),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            //handle others state
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemented my suggestion by using Yeasin Sheikh's sample code.
Because stream generator make a int value in sample code,
I used 'snapshot.requiredData' instead of 'snapshot.requiredData.length'.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: TSCState(),
    );
  }
}

class TSCState extends StatefulWidget {
  TSCState({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TSCStateState createState() => _TSCStateState();
}

class _TSCStateState extends State<TSCState> {
  var counterStream =
      Stream<int>.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (x) => x).take(15);

  int itemsCount;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<int>(
      stream: counterStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("total ${snapshot.requireData}"),
            ),
            body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text("Item $index"),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text("total")),
            body: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the AppBar title property with another StreamBuilder and then update it when your stream "theStream" finishes.

I uploaded an example code on this gist: https://gist.github.com/Alvarocda/140bbafb7eb24441ba9612a8ccf068ad

Basicaly, while _appBarCountStreamController has a null value on the stream, your appbar will be showing 'Loading'.

When your stream 'theStream' runs, you add the length of your list to __appBarCountStreamController and it will rebuild only the appbar title.

Dont forget to close _appBarCountStreamController on the dispose method.

Comment: this is a good idea. i will look into it late.